# Numpy: how to store indices of the form ":,:width,:" into a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

I have this code which I am trying to break differently:

```
if case1:
   if ncomp == 1:
      A[:,:width,:] = B[:,:width,:]
   else:
      A[:,:width,:,:] = B[:,:width,:,:]

elif case2:
   if ncomp == 1:
      A[:,:width] = B[:,:width]
   else:
      A[:,:width,:] = B[:,:width,:]
```

I would like something like this:

```
if case1:
   if ncomp == 1:
      indices_vec = LIST(:,:width,:);
   else:
      indices_vec = LIST(:,:width,:,:);

elif case2:
   if ncomp == 1:
      indices_vec = LIST(:,:width);
   else:
      indices_vec = LIST(:,:width,:);
A[indicies_vec] = B[indicies_vec]
```

Any idea whether I can indeed store such index notation "`:,:width,:`" into a variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`np.s_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html) object to store slices in numpy as variables then pass those as indices to arrays. As the docs mention, you can also create this with plain Python slice objects, but `np.s_` is much simpler and easier to read. For example:

```
width = 2

A = np.ones([3, 3, 3])
B = np.zeros([3, 3, 3])

indicies_vec = np.s_[:,:width,:];

A[indicies_vec] = B[indicies_vec]

print(A)
```

Which will give you the expected:

```
[[[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [1. 1. 1.]]

 [[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [1. 1. 1.]]

 [[0. 0. 0.]
  [0. 0. 0.]
  [1. 1. 1.]]]
```